# mail using PHP send a image tag

Tags: php

The following header informations I have added to send a html content as a mail message.

> $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .
>   "\r\n";
>
> $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;
>   charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
>
> $headers .= 'Content-type:
>   multypart/mixed;
>   boundary=\'PHP-mixed'."\r\n";
>
> $headers .=
>   "Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   8bit"."\r\n";
>
> $headers .= "Content-Type:
>   application/pdf;
>   name=/home/sugumar/LOGO2.jpg"."\r\n";
>
> mail($to, $subject, $message,
>   $headers);

In the HTML body tag has image tag. but in mail the image is not shown. how to send the image with mail. I don't want as a attachment. its like a inline content.

Comment: Where are you actually adding the image file to the E-Mail? Using a local path won't do. And note a typo in `multipart`... The standard answer to this would be use a ready-made mailing class like Swiftmailer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the image as an attachment if you want it inline.

What you do is in your HTML, instead of putting `<img src="filename.jpg" />`, you put the Content-ID of the image, i.e, `<img src="cid:$cid" />`

This article has a better breakdown with a working example:

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html